# Problema de SSL handshake failed Mongo DB con python

Tags: python, ssl, windows-server-2012, tls, mongoatlas

Tengo dos maquinas Windows Server 2012 ( uno en AWS y otra de manera física) ambos servidores.

He intentado realizar la conexión a un cluster de mongo (atlas) con los strings y ninguno funciona:

- `mongodb+srv://<usuario>:<password>@cluster0.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net/local`
- `mongodb+srv://<usuario>:<password>@cluster0.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net/local?ssl=true`
- `mongodb+srv://<usuario>:<password>@cluster0.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net/local?tls=true`
- `mongodb+srv://<usuario>:<password>@cluster0.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net/local?tls=true`
- 'mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net/local?retryWrites=true&w=majority', tls=True, tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True)`

**Tengo el codigo en python con el que he tratado de conectarme a mongo**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

print("Inicio")
## Aqui hice varios cambios en el string y como parametros
myclient = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://<usuario>:<password>@cluster0.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net/local')

print("Conexion Lista")

nombres = myclient.list_database_names()
print("nombres")
print(nombres)
print("fin")
```

*Versión Python 3.7*
*Versión Pymongo 4.5.0*
*Versión de Cluster mongo 6.0.10, en region AWS N.Virginia
*tambien lo intente directamente desde vscode*

---

**Tengo como respuesta**

```
Inicio
Conexion Lista
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\Downloads\new.py", line 9, in <module>
    nombres = myclient.list_database_names()
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1997, in list_database_names
    return [doc["name"] for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True, comment=comment)]
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1970, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 1028, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(_cmd, read_preference, session)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\_csot.py", line 108, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1525, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(read_pref, session, address=address)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1297, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 312, in select_server
    server = self._select_server(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 296, in _select_server
    servers = self.select_servers(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 247, in select_servers
    server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 270, in _select_servers_loop
    f"{self._error_message(selector)}, Timeout: {timeout}s, Topology Description: {self.description!r}"
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-02.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1091),SSL handshake failed: ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-01.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1091),SSL handshake failed: ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-00.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1091), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6514bd5bb2ad861aed8ba6a7, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-00.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-00.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1091)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-01.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-01.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1091)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-02.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-02.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1091)')>]>
```

---

He intentando resolver el problema de varias maneras:

- Cambiando las claves y registros de Windows
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#configure-for-strong-cryptography
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnp88.png)
  https://success.outsystems.com/support/troubleshooting/application_runtime/enable_ssl_for_your_integrations_tls_1.1_and_tls_1.2/
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mcaO.png)
- instalar Openssl
  https://tecadmin.net/install-openssl-on-windows/
- Abriendo puertos 27017, 10255, 44211
  porque vi que al usar wireshark usaban esos puertos que apuntaba en esa dirección.
- Use una herramienta IIS Crypto, para verificar y probar la conexión.
  [IIS Crypto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v77l8.png)

Ninguno de los intentos ha funcionado en los Windows Server 2012 y veo que tambien hay algo parecido al ser Windows 7, pero todo se centra en esta respuesta de error, si alguien pudiera saber que hace falta:
SSL handshake failed: ac-2ty4aal-shard-00-00.x0ocbpp.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1091)

> Nota: en mi ambiente de desarrollo con Windows 10 todo anda de maravilla, y no me da ningun error de conexión, use tls o ssl o incluso el puerto local este cerrado.

**

> Antes de enviar el post logre resolver el tema, y es por permisos de
> IP, Atlas tiene un Network Access, y con ello se indica una whitelist
> de ip, espero que a alguien mas le sirva.

**

Comment: Estás colocando como IP en MongoDB server 0.0.0.0/0 o solo tu dirección IP